# PrintCommandListener is missing

Tags: java, import, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file via FTP client using Java, but when trying the:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
```

the PrintCommandListener is show in red.  I verified my library and it does include commons.net.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

PrintCommandListener is in fact in Apache Commons Net.  For example, if you download the current version, the jar you need to include in your build path is commons-net-3.3.jar.  If this single jar is seen by your compiler, then the class should be recognized.  Make sure there are no other classes called PrintCommandListener (for example custom ones that you might have written) in your build path.

If using an IDE (such as eclipse) make sure the jar is on your build path.  For example, with Eclipse right click project, go to Java Build Path and click Add JARs.  Navigate to the location of your jar file and add it.